# Why does this recursive javascript function return what it does?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
var fn = function even (n) {
  if (n === 0) {
     return true
  }
   else return !even(n - 1)
 }

 fn(5)//=> false

 fn(2)  //=> true
```

Why does this function work the way it does?  When I step through it when the argument is 5 it seems to call itself until n is zero which would return true but it returns false.

Comment: try writing it out what it does step by step

Comment: It is because every recursive call reverse the value of the boolean, so if it is a multiple of 2 it will return true . Any other vase would be false

Comment: On each recursive call, the returned value is negated. Then `!!!!!false` is `true`. In short: **The result is negated when `!` is applied odd times**

Comment: The same function can be rewritten using modulo operator as `function isEven(num) { return num % 2 === 0; }`

Comment: @Tushar, instead of the expensive modulo you can use bit-operations for this: `var isEven = n=> (n&1)===0` or `var isEven = n => !(n&1)`; but this is OT

Comment: It's funny that on my Chrome it works if your `n` is `<= 31379`, otherwise it throws a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every recursion step adds a negation to the previous result:

```
f(0) = true
f(1) = !f(0) = !true = false
f(2) = !f(1) = !!f(0) = !!true = !false = true
```

and so on, for f(5) you get

```
f(5)
    !f(4)
        !!f(3)
            !!!f(2)
                !!!!f(1)
                    !!!!!f(0)
                    !!!!(!true)
                !!!(!false)
            !!(!true)
        !(!false)
    !true
false
```

Comment: I didn't realize that the ! would accumulate.  Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the **!**

When the function is 0 it return true.

When it's 1 it will return !even(0) -> false.

When it's 2 it will return !even(1) => !(!even(0)) => !(false)=> true.

Since boolean is either true of false, meaning two possible value and you switch them again and again it works.